# json encode array returns empty

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi I have an example of an array that I'm using.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [volumes_show] => Array ( [0] => 0.1-2.5Î¼l [1] => 0.1-3Î¼l [2] => 0.5-10Î¼l [3] => 0.5-10Î¼l [4] => 0.5-10Î¼l [5] => 0.5-10Î¼l [6] => 10-100Î¼l [7] => 10-100Î¼l [8] => 100-1000Î¼l [9] => 100-1000Î¼l [10] => 2-20Î¼l [11] => 2-20Î¼l [12] => 20-200Î¼l [13] => 20-200Î¼l [14] => 30-300Î¼l [15] => 5-100Î¼l [16] => 5-50Î¼l [17] => 5-50Î¼l [18] => 50-300Î¼l ) [models_show] => Array ( [0] => mLine [1] => Proline ) )
```

I used json_encode and it returns this value.

```
[[]]
```

I'm still trying to figure out whats wrong. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the php

```
$data = array();
    $data['models_show'] = array();
    $data['volumes_show'] = array();    
    $data = array($data['models_show'],$data['models_show']);
    $brand = $_GET['Bname'];
    $data['volumes_show'] =$volumes[$brand];
    $data['models_show'] =$models[$brand];
    sort($data['volumes_show']);
    echo json_encode(array_unique($data));
```

Here are the values:

```
$brands= array('Biohit','Brand','Eppendorf','Thermo/Finn','Gilson','Nichiryo','Rainin','Socorex');
$models = array('Biohit' => array('mLine','Proline'));
    $volumes = array( 'Biohit' => array('0.1-3μl','0.5-10μl','2-20μl','10-100μl','20-200μl','100-1000μl','0.5-10μl','5-100μl','30-300μl','0.1-2.5μl','0.5-10μl','2-20μl','5-50μl','10-100μl','20-200μl','100-1000μl','0.5-10μl','5-50μl','50-300μl'),'Brand' => array('0.1-1μl','0.5-10μl','2-20μl micro','2-20μl','5-50μl','10-100μl','20-200μl','100-1000μl','0.5-10μl','2-20μl','2.5-25μl','5-50μl','10-100μl','20-200μl','30-300μl','0.1-1μl','0.1-2.5μl','0.5-10μl','2-20μl','10-100μl','20-200μl','100-1000μl','0.5-10μl','5-50μl','10-100μl','20-200μl'),'Eppendorf' => array('10-100μl','30-300μl','0.1-2.5μl','0.5-10μl','2-20μl micro','50-200μl','100-1000μl'),'Thermo/Finn' => array(),'Gilson' => array(),'Nichiryo' => array(),'Rainin' => array(),'Socorex' => array() );
```

Comment: `0.1-2.5Î¼l`? Can you please post some actual PHP code?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I don't think that PHP code works. You might want to edit it.

Comment: Updated the post above.

Comment: I can't make your code work at all. But I'll give you a tip: use `var_dump()` (and I mean `var_dump()`, not `print_r()` or `echo`) to inspect every single piece of data right before you use it. Use your browser's "View Source" menu to inspect the output of `var_dump()` (and I mean that, not Firebug's HTML pane or the rendered view). Use that info to detect the exact line where something goes wrong. Once you know the line that's wrong, if you still cannot figure out yourself, you just need to post a data sample and the function call.

Answer (score -1):

`μ` character is not being written correctly. You must change all `μ` characters in your code with its html entity encoding character :

`&mu;`

An array example:

```
array('0.1-3&mu;l');
```

Check [Unicode Character 'GREEK SMALL LETTER MU'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm)